# Updating with multiple select <option selected="selected">

Tags: php, html, mysql, arrays, multiple-select

I have a form where a user can update several data inside the database and one of the fields is using a multiple select. I'm stuck with the selected part, where the system will display back the keyword values from the database in the option. The updating process works fine, the problem is only to display the existing values from the database inside the multiple select options.

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <?php
    if(isset($_GET['edit'])) {
        $id = $_GET['edit'];
        $query = "SELECT * FROM record WHERE id = $id";
        $select_id = mysqli_query($con,$query);
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($select_id)){
            $keywords = explode (', ', $row['record_keywords']) ;
            ?>
            <label class="control-label">Keywords</label>
            <select multiple name="keywords[]" type="next" class="selectpicker" data-style="btn btn-default btn-block">
                <?php
                $query = "SELECT * FROM key";
                $select_categories = mysqli_query($con,$query);
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($select_categories)) {
                    $kk = $row['key'] == $keywords;
                    echo '<option '.($kk ? 'selected="selected"' : '').'>' . $row['key'] . '</option>';
                } ?>
            </select>

            <button class="btn btn-warning btn-fill btn-wd btn-finish pull-right" name="update" type="submit">Update</button>
            <?php
        }//end of while
    }//end of if
    ?>
</form>
```

Comment: You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of concatenating your queries. Specially since you're not escaping the user inputs at all!

Comment: `$keywords` is an array and won't match the `$row['key']`, which is a string. Try to use [`in_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) to check if the keyword exists in the array: `in_array($row['key'], $keywords)`.

Comment: To make your life much easier, your should also [normalize your database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) instead of storing multiple values in one column.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson hey, thanks a lot ! It works now. I just change $kk = $row['key'] == $keywords; to $kk = in_array($row['key'], $keywords); . thanks also for the advise, I will go through it one by one, i'm still a beginner, still need to learn many things about php. Anyway, TQ :)